# save style for each field in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use mongodb and I have a model like this:

```
{
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
}
```

I want to save styles (such as font, size, color, etc.) for ***each field***

What is the best way to store them in a database?

Do I have to create a new field for each of them to store their style as a string (HTML code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the list of css class like what bootstrap does. And then, you will create a new filed for each of them where you will just store the classes name.

- all css will be stored in the css files
- classes names associated to each elements will be stored in the database.

In that way, your app will be stay clean and you can reuse a lot of css class.